# How to make autocomplete works with the Japanese language?

Tags: views, search

I'm working on setting up search with the Search API module and Elasticsearch, for the Japanese language.

Following what described in [How to implement Japanese full-text search in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-implement-japanese-full-text-search-in-elasticsearch), I created an `EventSubscriber` class to change the index settings and the field mappings.

The search is working fine. The problem is with the autocomplete: I do not get results.

Following what described in [Implementing Japanese autocomplete suggestions in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/implementing-japanese-autocomplete-suggestions-in-elasticsearch), I am not able to make my code work, since it's based on keyword not fullText field.

```php
public function overrideMapping(Event $event) {
  $params = $event->getIndexMappingParams();

  foreach ($params['body']['properties'] as $key => &$value) {
    if ($value['type'] == 'text') {
      $value['search_analyzer'] = 'ja_kuromoji_search_analyzer';
      $value['analyzer'] = 'ja_kuromoji_index_analyzer';
      $value['fields'] = [
        'ngram' => [
          "type" => "text",
          "search_analyzer" => "ja_ngram_search_analyzer",
          "analyzer" => "ja_ngram_index_analyzer"
        ],
        'suggest' => [
          'type' => 'text',
          'search_analyzer' => 'suggest_search_analyzer',
          'analyzer' => 'suggest_index_analyzer'
        ],
        'readingform' => [
          'type' => 'text',
          'search_analyzer' => 'readingform_search_analyzer',
          'analyzer' => 'readingform_index_analyzer'
        ]
      ];
    }
  }

  $event->setIndexMappingParams($params);
}
```

The settings are the same in the autocomplete documentation.

Do you have any idea about this?